# Python : Get information from multiple tables sql, and fill Dash

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql, plotly-dash

I have multiple tables in a db SQL.
I am trying to do Join so that I can have a several information from each table.
The select works, the data also ( when I print it, It has data), but I cannot fill the table in Dash. It goes empty with the columns that I created

Something is wrong... Thank you in advance

```
conn = script.connect_to_db(host, user, psw, db_name, port)
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_statement ="""SELECT li.book_name,au.autor_name,bo.references
FROM library li
INNER JOIN autors au ON au.id=li.id_autors
INNER JOIN books bo ON bo.id_references=au.id
"""
cursor.execute(sql_statement)

data=cursor.fetchall()
print('data',data)

columslist = [
    {"name": ["book name"], "id": "book_name", "type": 'text'},
    {"name": ["autors"], "id": "autors", "type": 'text'},
    {"name": ["references"], "id": "references", "type": 'text'},

]

layout = html.Div([
    html.Br(),
    html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-library',
        columns=columslist ,
        data=data,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data should be in `dictionry` datatype :

```
layout = html.Div([
    html.Br(),
    html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-library',
        columns=columslist ,
        data=dict(data),
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. I tried the code but I get : ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required ...